# What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string / URL?

Tags: postgresql, database-connection

What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string (URL `postgres://...`) when the host is not the localhost?

Comment: This link provides information about connection string, driver class, and driver library. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3497/agqka/index.html Also to download the recent jar files, use this link: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: This might be useful: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/postgresql#connection-details

Comment: e.g `postgres://postgres:123456@127.0.0.1:5432/dummy`

Comment: Related question about pgAdmin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479570/how-to-connect-to-database-through-jdbc-in-pgadmin#comment125419866_62014740

Answer (score 1013):

If you use Libpq binding for respective language, according to its [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) URI is formed as follows:

```
postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]
```

Here are examples from same document

```
postgresql://
postgresql://localhost
postgresql://localhost:5432
postgresql://localhost/mydb
postgresql://user@localhost
postgresql://user:secret@localhost
postgresql://other@localhost/otherdb?connect_timeout=10&application_name=myapp
postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=other&password=secret
```

Comment: This workded for me postgres://user:secret@localhost:5432/mydatabasename

Comment: `postgresql://localhost/mydb?user=other&password=secret` did the trick

Comment: If you still have problems, check the special characters in your password, change it temporarily for only numbers and test the URL (just to validate that your connection is working as expected)

Comment: My issue was to simply copying the "jdbc:postgres:// ..." string out of DataGrip. Unfortunately the error message did not help. Thank you!

Comment: To add to @Edenshaw's note on special characters, the password needs to be url encoded, I just stumbled upon this problem with a password containing the '@' character (replacing it with %40 solved it)

Comment: Weirdly enough, I think it's supposed to be `ApplicationName` and not `application_name`. I tried a `show application_name;` query and it only used the application name I supplied if I supplied it as `ApplicationName=whatever` in the connection string.

Comment: Strange, i could only get the jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB?user=X&password=Y syntax to work, not the user:password@host. Using version postgresql-42.3.3.jar

Comment: For me this one worked
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/mydb?user=user&password=secret

The below one didn't worked for me
postgresql://user:secret@localhost:port/mydb

Answer (score 248):

The following worked for me

```
const conString = "postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@YourHostname:5432/YourDatabaseName";
```

Comment: How to use this connection string in ruby?

Comment: is 'postgres://' and 'postgresql://' interchangeable ?

Comment: @RyuS. 

`The URI scheme designator can be either postgresql:// or postgres://`

From here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING

Comment: In case your hostname is a url, you can use `ping hostname` to get IP address.

Comment: Thank you this is the simpliest answer. Thanks @Hemadri Dasari

Answer (score 128):

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://{user}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{database-name}
```

Answer (score 40):

[Here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/use/#connecting-to-the-database) is the documentation for JDBC, the general URL is "jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database"

Chapter 3 [here](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) documents the ADO.NET connection string,
the general connection string is `Server=host;Port=5432;User Id=username;Password=secret;Database=databasename;`

PHP documentation us [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pgsql.php), the general connection string is
`host=hostname port=5432 dbname=databasename user=username password=secret`

If you're using something else, you'll have to tell us.

Comment: Thanks. The ADO.NET format is also what you need to pass to `UseNpgsql()` for Entity Framework Core.  I was a little confused whether it should be that or the postgres:// URL (which I've also seen as "postgresql://")

Comment: libpq (offical postgresql client lib)  understands both URL form and name=value pairs form. if you connection is not ultimately through libpq then consult the documentation for your framework.

Comment: First link is broken (JDBC documentation)

Answer (score 11):

the connection url for postgres
syntax:

```
"Server=host ipaddress;Port=5432;Database=dbname;User Id=userid;Password=password;
```

example:

```
"Server=192.168.1.163;Port=5432;Database=postgres;User Id=postgres;Password=root;
```

Answer (score 9):

- The general format of database url

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://username:password@host:port/dtabase_name
```

- If you are using postgresql sql with asyncpg the database url would be

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://username:password@host:port/dtabase_name
```

> > - Remember to never push your  database password so you should use your `DATABASE_URL` in `.env` file
> > - The `port` is optional if you use the default one

- Like this you can connect both local and remote database think of that once you want to check an issue that occur in the remote deployed versions
- ex of localhost DATABASE_URL would be

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://postgres:dina@localhost/mysens
```

- If you deployed your database on Heroku and you want to connect it with your local app, go to Heroku Postgres installed add-on go to settings and click on view credential in Database Credentials and use the `uri` to connect to your database

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql+asyncpg://sqnalxxxxxxxxx:160xxxx2bdd2942b26c93c392xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@ec2-35-173-91-114.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/del6o4cjoqfsov
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The connection string can also be retrieved programmatically from working DB connectors.

For instance I sometimes extract connection strings from SQLAlchemy's `engine`, like this:

```
> db_engine.url
postgres://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{db_name}?sslmode=require
```

Answer (score 4):

```
server.address=10.20.20.10
server.port=8080
database.user=username
database.password=password
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${server.address}/${server.port}?user=${database.user}&password=${database.password}
```

Comment: Not valid way to define connection URI

Comment: This is not a valid approach for Postgress

Comment: What about database name? Why database is on the same port as the server?

Answer (score 2):

*To add more: if you want to find out the values for the url,, in **pgAdmin panel***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some people seem to misread the database name as a server name and the host as a postgresql server? A host hosts a postgresql server that has a database. Or am I missing something.

> postgresql://my_host/&server=my_postgresql_server?user=my_user&port=my_port&password=my_password&database=my_database

Example:

my_host: can be "localhost" (but that is not in the question) or an ip address of a host.

> postgresql://my_host/&server=postgres?user=postgres&port=5432&password=postgres&database=test_db

Worked for me in Python with sqlalchemy and a postgresql localhost running. Needs sqlalchemy, postgresql, and psycopg2 to get it to work.

PS: The question is about a postgres://... URL, but this would not work here. Instead, you need *postgresql*, and what is run in the end in Python is dialect+driver (see [Database URLs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#database-urls)) = *postgresql+psycopg2*, without having to write it like this.