# How to connect to database through JDBC in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pgadmin

I have database connection settings and pgAdmin (it is all that i have). Can I connect to the database through the pgAdmin to make the necessary changes in the database using these settings? If so, how?

I have not found how I can do this. Other answers here (and in google too) suggest writing Java-code - this is not what i need. I want to use pgAdmin interface for it. Can I make changes without using Java-code?

Here example of settings that i have:

```
jdbc.driverClassName - org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url - jdbc:postgresql://localhost:4444/
jdbc.username - username
jdbc.password - password
```

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't use JDBC. But it's not clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve? Do you have a problem with connecting pgAdmin to your Postgres server? If yes, what is the problem (or the error message). If not, then why ask for JDBC connections? And what kind of changes do you want to make? To the table definitions? To the data? To the queries?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I want to add some records to the table or at least see if they already exist. In general, I just want to visualize the data in the database (to know how to work with it).

Comment: Then connect with pgAdmin, and use the SQL editor to run `insert` statements

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can I do this using the settings that I already have?

Comment: PgAdmin is a web-based query tool for PostgreSQL, it doesn't use Java, so it cannot use JDBC. It is unclear what you really want to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why people don't understand what he's trying to do. He just wants to connect to db using pgAdmin. He just doesn't understand how to use the connection string in pgAdmin.

Basically, just remove all prefixes and suffixes (eg. jdbc:postgresql://). So your hostname is localhost. Type `localhost` in host name, `4444` in port name as well as your username and password. Also give it a name in General tab Then you'll see the databases on the left. Click `Tools > Query Tool` and write your select/insert etc. scripts.

[image]

Comment: Does pgAdmin really not support a way to add a server via pasting a connection string? I feel like it's reasonable to expect that feature, so I'm betting that it exists and I just don't see it.

Comment: See question: https://superuser.com/questions/1717071/how-create-new-server-connection-in-pgadmin-4-by-pasting-postgresql-connection-s