# How to connect pgAdmin server to get databases in DataGrip

Tags: database, database-connection, pgadmin, datagrip

How can I open Database (e.g. connect pgAdmin server) made in pgAdmin?

I tried to set same host (localhost or adres 127.0.0.1) but it didn't work.

I'm new in this field and I don't know how to use this tools very well so I would like some help. Do I need SQL Docker for this? What is actually a Docker?

Comment: Please show the connection dialog in pg_admin

Comment: A database made in pgAdmin would be a PostgreSQL one. In order to connect to it from DataGrip, you need to create a PostgreSQL data source (see guide and video example here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2022.3/postgresql.html), and fill out its settings with the connection parameters (hostname, port, etc.) which you can obtain from pgAdmin's 'Connection' dialog (example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62014740/12594975). 
Docker is a separate technology not necessarily needed to connect to databases. WRT to DataGrip, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2022.3/docker.html

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DataGrip Quick Start guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/quick-start-with-datagrip.html) where everything is well described