# Docker - URL syntax

Tags: docker, http, url

I came accross a URL syntax in a config file, but I don't get the meaning of some of it:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://myuser:myuser@db:5432/db_prod
```

More specifically:

1. the `//myuser:myuser` part. This is the url that Flask (a web service in my docker-compose file) uses to connect to the db (postgres). The username for the postgres db is indeed myuser as defined in POSTGRES_USER environment variable, however I don't get why this is repeated here.
2. The meaning of `=postgresql:`. That's not the name of my service, nor the name of the image (which is `postgres:13.1`).

The rest is clear to me:

- `db`: name of the service in the docker network
- `db_prod`: name of the database to connect to
- `5432`: the port on which the db services listen to on the local docker network

thanks!

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/postgresql-connection-url

Syntax : postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]

Comment: `DATABASE_URL=...` probably assigns that URL to an environment variable or similar setting.  The URL syntax is explained pretty well in the question @sanjay cites (and follows the generic URL `scheme://user:pass@host:port/path` syntax).

Comment: *facepalm* yes that actually makes sense. I was so deep thinking about docker configs that it didn't really occur to me this isn't so much a docker question as a postgres question. THank you.