# Can't connect to postgresql (jdbc) from Intellij (installed as flatpak on linux mint)

Tags: java, linux, postgresql, intellij-idea, jdbc

Debugging stops on error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /run/host/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/conf/logging.properties (No such file or directory).
As a result, the java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError error pops up.

Error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /run/host/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/conf/logging.properties (No such file or directory)

Error on this line:
`DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jc_student", "postgres", "999999");`

(java 11)

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation: The URL string is missing a `/` between `5432` (port number) and `jc_student` (db name). See [What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string / URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url) I have never seen that Java error, as it relates to the Java installation itself. Perhaps you have an incorrectly installed Java platform.

Comment: You can try to install the IDE as a standalone version. Probably, it's a problem on the flatpak version.

Comment: Looks like in your program you are supplying or use the `java.util.logging.config.file` system property somewhere. Double check this. It may also be some Application Server configuration if you deploy the application on the application server. usually the place where this property is evaluated can be seen in the full stack trace you get. But you did not post it.

Comment: i think the problem is that Intellij is installed in linux as flatpak. I copied this file to my home folder and wrote:
System.setProperty ("java.util.logging.config.file", "/home/il/logging.properties");
This problem was solved, but I don't like this solution.
And another error appeared (FileNotFoundException):
"file: /usr/share/java/java-atk-wrapper.jar".
I don't have this file in this path.

Comment: Maybe windows should be installed? Lots of problems with Intellij