# How to make PostgreSQL database accessible all the time from different computers?

Tags: postgresql

I've created simple PostgreSQL database on my localhost and connected it to my project. I want to pass the project to someone else and share the same database. Also i want my db to run 24h per day and be accessible without previous switching on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see. It is a lot of spec. Fortunately, the solution for your problem is simple: **move your database** from local machine (your PC/laptop) to a network-connected server. Below is step-by-step list of what you need to do:

1. Find a decent PostgreSQL DB provider (some paid, some free), for example: [Amazon RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) , [ElephantSQL](https://www.elephantsql.com/), [Azure PostgreSQL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/postgresql/). Then create an instance.
   Or you can setup a server and [install PostgreSQL](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-18-04). Either works fine.
2. Change the connection from `localhost:5432` to new server. There is no detail on question, so I'll provide an [example of connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url):
   `postgres://{remoteuser}:{password}@{remotehost}:{port}/{dbname}`
3. If your local database already contain data, [copy it to new database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U localuser dbname | psql -h remotehost -U remoteuser dbname
```