# Liquibase can not read jdbc postegresql connection string with username and password

Tags: liquibase

The [documentation on the Liquibase website](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/postgresql.html) says that I can use the full connection string in the `--url` parameter such as

`jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=user&password=secret`

yet when I run any command such as

`liquibase history --url='jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=user&password=secret'`

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://host:5432/database?user=user with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  The server requested password-based authentication, but no password was provided.

For more information, please use the --log-level flag
'password' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It looks like the `&` makes Liquibase split the connection string into two commands. It works if I provide the `--user` and `--password` parameters separately : `liquibase history --url='jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database --user='user' --password='secret'`.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm running this in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string should look something like:

postgresql://[user[:password]@][netloc][:port][/dbname][?param1=value1&...]

So it should be:

```
liquibase history --url='jdbc:postgresql://user:password@host:port/database'
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20722229/2864019

Comment: I get a generic 'The connection attempt failed.' error