# create schema on created database on pg-app-dev-vm

Tags: postgresql, vagrant

I've cloned this [Github repository](https://github.com/jackdb/pg-app-dev-vm) PostgreSQL VM via Vagrant. Been trying to create a new schema `test` but it always ends up under `postgres` database. Considering the create database is named `myapp`, how can I create the `test` schema under `myapp` database?

I've been trying to add this script under the `Vagrant-setup/bootstrap.sh`.

```
cat << EOF | su - postgres -c psql myapp

create schema test;

EOF
```

Comment: When connected to the database myapp you can't create a schema (or any other database object) in another database. If it happens that a database object ends up in the wrong database, you were connected to the wrong database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reference it may help to check your connection string in order to ensure you are connected to the right database. The official postgresql documentation is quite helpful here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html

This may help as well for understanding the format:

[What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string / URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url)

Outside of that you will have to ensure permissions are set appropriately for the user to create schemas in the database and to configure the search_path for easy access to objects under the schema.