# Docker java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Database name postgresql not supported

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, spring-data-jpa

I created application spring + postgeSQL +docker

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.password=rfnfdfcbz123!
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:11.1:///mesh_group
spring.jpa.show-sql=true spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD /target/DockerLearn-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar backend123.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/backend123.jar"]
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:11.1'
    container_name: 'java-postgres124'
    environment:
      - 'POSTGRES_USER=postgres'
      - 'POSTGRES_PASSWORD=rfnfdfcbz123!'
      - 'POSTGRES_DB=mesh_group'

app:
  build: ./
  container_name: 'java-app124'
  ports:
    - 8000:8080
```

when i run java-app124 .  docker send error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Database name postgresql not supported
at org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver.connect(ContainerDatabaseDriver.java:106) ~[jdbc-1.17.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar!/:na]
at
```

Comment: Why you try to run the postgresql as a test container?

Comment: i am studying Docker .i am trying send image database + java application on another machine. how  i can do it without postgresql  test container ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the format for the PostgreSQL connection string / URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error I thinking adding this dependency helped

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>1.17.6</version>
    </dependency>
```