# I'm trying to start my server but I'm getting an error "throw new Error('SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string')

Tags: node.js, psql

This line of code is the issue , once i remove it, i can start the server right away

```html
const { Client } = require("pg");

let DB_URI;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  DB_URI = "postgresql:///users_test";
} else {
  DB_URI = "postgresql:///users";
}

let db = new Client({
  connectionString: DB_URI
});

db.connect();

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: Which line of code?

Comment: The entire line of code , it looks like i need a password for psql ,to be able to connect the database

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url

Comment: let db = new Client({
  connectionString: DB_URI
})

Comment: Your connection string is invalid