Required Variable in .env file to connect to remote postgres sql database
Working with an application that runs on docker that has migrated from mongo to postgres for database. Looking for what variable or what i need to add into the docker .env file to point to a remote postgres sql database instead of the local docker image. the data base sits on a separate server, but not sure how to configure the .env file to point to that database, previously the mongo string was already in the .env for the application just had to point to a host instead of localhost but the new .env does not have that, just the below variables.
`*DATA_DIR=/var/data/

`POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*
`POSTGRES_USER=*
`POSTGRES_DB=*

tried browsing the internet for this but have not found an answer to my question yet.

Your env file feeds your other container(s) so they can connect to the database, so you have to see for yourself what those other(s) container(s) requires as connection information.

This said, like for MongoDB, Postgres connection information can also be expressed as a connection string. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582552/what-is-the-format-for-the-postgresql-connection-string-url
