# Using pg_dump to take a snapshot of a database

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to setup a script to take a copy of a database from one server to another.

Thanks to this post [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/how-to-copy-postgres-database-to-another-server) I have found a way to do that.

But what I need to do is change the name of the database during the copy.
I have thought about using sed and doing a simple text replace. But I am worried that this could corrupt the database.

Does any one know the proper way of doing this?

**As requested here are the commands I am using**

```
pg_dump -C -U remoteuser -h remoteServer dbname | psql -h localhost -U localadmin template1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just restore to a different database. For `pg_restore` of `-Fc` dumps from `pg_dump`'s custom format:

```
createdb newdbname
pg_restore --dbname newdbname database.dump
```

For SQL-format dumps *not* created with the `-C` option to `pg_dump`:

```
createdb newdbname
psql -f database_dump.sql newdbname
```

If you're streaming the dump from a remote host, just omit `-f database_dump.sql` as the dump data is coming from stdin.

You can't easily `CREATE DATABASE` in the same command as your restore, because you need to connect to a different DB like `template1` in order to create the new DB. So in your example you might:

```
psql -h localhost -U localadmin template1 -c 'CREATE DATABASE newdb;'
pg_dump -U remoteuser -h remoteServer dbname | psql -h localhost -U localadmin newdb
```

Note the omission of the `-C` flag to `pg_dump`.

The first command is just the longhand way of writing `createdb -h localhost -U localadmin newdb`.

---

**Update**: If you're stuck with a `pg_dump` created with the `-C` flag you can indeed just `sed` the dump so long as you're extremely careful. There should only be four lines (one a comment) at the start of the file that refer to the database name. For the database name "regress" dumped with Pg 9.1's `pg_dump -C`:

```
--
-- Name: regress; Type: DATABASE; Schema: -; Owner: craig
--

CREATE DATABASE regress WITH TEMPLATE = template0 ENCODING = 'UTF8' LC_COLLATE = 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_CTYPE = 'en_US.UTF-8';


ALTER DATABASE regress OWNER TO craig;

\connect regress
```

This can be transformed quite safely with three (or four if you want to rewrite the comment) very specific `sed` commands. Do *not* just do a global find and replace on the database name, though.

```
sed \
  -e 's/^CREATE DATABASE regress/CREATE DATABASE newdbname/' \
  -e 's/^ALTER DATABASE regress/ALTER DATABASE newdbname/' \
  -e 's/^\\connect regress/\\connect newdbname/' \
  -e 's/^--Name: regress/--Name: newdbname/'
```

This should be a last resort; it's much better to just dump without `-C`.