# Transfer PostgreSQL db to another server not on the same network

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to use the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/how-to-copy-postgres-database-to-another-server) to allow me to transfer my PostgreSQL dbs from an old server (sourcepc) to a new server (receiverpc) on a completely different network. I am therefore on sourcepc trying to push the db dump to receiverpc using the following command:

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U dbuser dbname | psql -h receiverpc_ipaddress -U dbuser dbname
```

This isn't working - it just sits there after the dbuser password is given.  I am running Ubuntu (9.10 on sourcepc, and 14.04 on receiverpc).  PostgreSQL is 8.4 on sourcepc and 9.3 on receiverpc.

What I've done:

1. Opened the firewall on receiverpc to allow  access to the PostgreSQL port.
2. Edited /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf on receiverpc to let it receive external addresses:

   listen_addresses = '*'
3. Edited /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf on receiverpc to add an entry for sourcepc:

   host    all             all             sourcepc_ipaddress/32                md5
4. Restarted PostgreSQL.

I can't really understand why it's not working.

Comment: Can you execute a simplest SQL command on `receiverpc` using such `psql` call? You'd rather check its working before transferring.

Comment: You may also want to consider splitting them into 2 separate commands, with the dump to an SQL file and the psql command using that file. Pipes, while convenient, can eat errors and result in hangs.

Answer (score 0):

@netch: Yes, it's working.

`echo "\dt" | psql -U dbuser -d dbname`

gives a list of the tables in a db.

@Ken Hampson: I think you're right.  I spent another 2 hours on this, fiddling about with pg_pass, etc, and finally decided it was less bother to just do:

`su - postgres`

`pg_dump --clean dbname > dbs/dbname.sql`

`scp -r dbs/ myuser@receiverpc:/home/myuser`

and then run psql on each database on receiverpc.

Thanks anyway.