# PostgreSQL - copy data from one table, database, server to another table, another database, server

Tags: postgresql

What would be the best way to copy data from one table, one database, one server to the table in another database, another server in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgdump.html) allows the dumping of only select tables:

```
pg_dump -Fc -f output.dump -t tablename databasename
```

*(dump 'tablename' from database 'databasename' into file 'output.dump' in pg_dumps binary custom format)*

You can restore that dump on your other server with [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-pgrestore.html):

```
pg_restore -d databasename output.dump
```

If the table itself already exists in your target database, you can import only the rows by adding the `--data-only` flag.

Comment: If you're using pgadmin3, you can run pg_dump/pg_restore by right clicking on a database or table and choosing the backup/restore menu items. It's OK for simple one off tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I shared a shell to copy table from one server to another PostgreSQL server.
Please refer this another stack question.
[Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)