# pg_dump from remote server to localhost

Tags: postgresql, ssh, pg-dump

Hi can anyone help me dump from a postgreSQL database on a remote AWS server to a postgreSQL database on my local machine.

I've been trying to do it using the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/how-to-copy-postgres-database-to-another-server) stack post but it keeps failing.

The command I'm using is

```
pg_dump -C -h ssh ubuntu@ec2-59-16-143-85.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -U dev_user paycloud_dev | psql -h localhost -U dev_user paycloud_dev
```

But I keep getting the error

```
pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "paycloud_dev")
```

Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Just to add, `dev_user` is the role I've set up in postgreSQL on both the local machine and remote server. `paycloud_dev` is the name of the database on both (owner is `dev_user`)

> **Edit 1**

Tried the command below as per a post that has since been deleted for some reason

```
pg_dump -C -h ec2-59-16-143-85.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -U dev_user paycloud_dev | psql -h localhost -U dev_user paycloud_dev
```

This is now giving me the error

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "paycloud_dev" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "ec2-59-16-143-85.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (59.16.143.85) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I went on to AWS and noted that is the elastic ip of the server. I then tried the following (the private IP address)

```
pg_dump -C -h 170.30.43.35 -U dev_user paycloud_dev | psql -h localhost -U dev_user paycloud_dev
```

This asks me for the password for paycloud_dev and when I enter it pauses for a good 2 or 3 minutes and comes back with:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "paycloud_dev" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "170.30.43.35" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've tried editing the AWS security group to add a rule that accepts all traffic (port range 0-65535) but the same error is occurring.

> **Edit 2**

Tried the following as per post by pokoli

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2-59-16-143-85.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com pg_dump -C -h  -U dev_user paycloud_dev | psql -U dev_user paycloud_dev
```

It's not working though. It first asks me for the psql password for my laptop then before I can input anything, it gives an error.

```
[sudo] password for alzer: pg_dump: too many command-line arguments (first is "paycloud_dev")
```

Try "pg_dump --help" for more information.

Anyone?

Comment: Your PostgreSQL may not be allowing outside connections. See [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html) on how to allow it. Also if you're using firewall, you need to allow inbound connection to TCP port 5432, unless you use non-standard port.

Comment: The answer that you link to is nothing like the command that you posted.

Answer (score 9):

You have to connect with ssh to remote host, execute the dump and pipe it to your local machine. The following command should do:

```
ssh ubuntu@ec2-59-16-143-85.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -C pg_dump  -U dev_user paycloud_dev | psql -U dev_user paycloud_dev
```

The command will ask for password of both users if needed and the `playcloud_dev` database should exists on localhost, otherwise the dump will fail.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this when at my machine this evening.

Comment: Sorry it was an error on commandline (-C must be before pg_dump and -h flag is not required). Could you try with the new command?

Comment: No that's failing as well - Tried a few variations but getting the error `[sudo] password for alzer: pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "paycloud_dev" failed: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "dev_user"`

Comment: @AI-D was able to pull this off using another type of connection string to Postgres.. Maybe you can try that too? `ssh -i <path to keypair.pem file> <EC2 server on AWS with SSH access> -C "pg_dump -Fc postgresql://<postgres username>@<RDS server host on AWS>:5432/<remote database name>" | pg_restore -d <local database name> `

Answer (score 3):

Try do this over ssh tunnel.

```
ssh -fT -L 5432:127.0.0.1:5432 %remote_user_login%@%your_aws_host% sleep 10
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U dev_user paycloud_dev | psql -h localhost -U dev_user paycloud_dev
```

First line create ssh tunnel and port mapping.

And view your AWS security settings in "Security Groups", may be you forgot opening ports.

Comment: If you need to pass a password to pg_dump, the easiest way is "env PGPASSWORD=xxx pg_dump ...".