# How to move Postgresql 10 server to a new host?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql 10 database server which was built on a temporary host while awaiting new hardware. Now that we have the new hardware in place, I need to move the database server to the new host.
Where can I find the steps for doing that?

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)

Comment: I don't want to copy the database, I need to copy the entire server, including it's name, space and all configs. I saw plenty of notes on copying a database, but it's the server, not only the database I need to copy.