# How do i import .csv file from a remote server to a postgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

The original code is a simple SQL import :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/FTP/foo/foo.csv'

INTO TABLE error_logs

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
ESCAPED BY ''
LINES STARTING BY ''
TERMINATED BY '\n' 

IGNORE 1 LINES

(Server,Client,Error,Time);
```

I need to migrate a web portal (from SQL to Postgres[I know there are tools for that, but its not the question]) and the issue is i am no more working on local.

I didn't see anybody ask the question in this way : import .csv from a remote server to a postgres db.

I think i have to use COPY but i dont get the right syntax...

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

the copy command is an option to do this.

I had to do this once time.

[How to import CSV file data into a PostgreSQL table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987433/how-to-import-csv-file-data-into-a-postgresql-table)

[Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Matter is i dont want to dump the db but simply import a csv from a remote server in the postgres database.