# Is there any approach to migrate PostgreSQL database from Azure to AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, azure, migration

I able to migrate from on-prem database to AWS using DMS service but couldn't able to migrate database from Azure to AWS.

Is there any better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)

Comment: Why wouldn't at least some of the standard migration techniques still work in an cloud environment?

Answer (score 0):

A pretty low level but effective way would be to: export your Azure data as CSV using pg_dump,
copy it into an AWS S3 bucket (pretty easy with Python awscli package) and [load from S3 into RDS Postgres](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL.Procedural.Importing.html#USER_PostgreSQL.S3Import).

Would be great if files could be moved directly from blob storage to s3, but I don't think Azure Postgres supports dumping directly to blob anyway.