# How to copy a table with millions of rows from PostgreSQL to Amazon Redshift using pandas or python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, amazon-redshift, dask

What is the best possible way to copy a table (with millions of rows) from one type of database to other type using pandas or python?

I have a table in PostreSQL database consisting of millions of rows, I want to move it to Amazon Redshift. What can be the best possible way to achieve that using pandas or python?

Comment: best way could be to use Postgresql tools to copy it without using python or pandas: [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)

Comment: What do you mean by "best"?

Answer (score 1):

The **Amazon Database Migration Service** (DMS) can handle:

- [Using a PostgreSQL Database as a Source for AWS DMS - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html)
- [Using an Amazon Redshift Database as a Target for AWS Database Migration Service - AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html)

Alternatively, if you wish to do it yourself:

- Export the data from PostgreSQL into CSV files (they can be gzip compressed)
- Upload the files to Amazon S3
- Create the destination tables in Amazon Redshift
- Use the `COPY` command in Amazon Redshift to load the CSV files into Redshift

Comment: I use the `copy` command. It's actually the best way to insert tons of data on an existent table.

Answer (score 0):

- If you're *using Aws services* it might be good to use aws Glue, it uses ***python*** scripts for its ETL operations, very optimal for Dynamo-->Redshift for example.
- If you're *not using only Aws services*, Try to Export your Redshift data as csv? (i did this for millions of rows) & create a migration tool using c# or whatever to read the csv file & insert your rows after converting them or whatever [***Check if the Database technology you're using can take the csv directly so you can avoid doing the migration yourself***].