# how copy/transfer complet.BD.postgres from SERVER1 directly to SERVER2?

Tags: postgresql

Many webs (as StackOverFlow: [Copying PostgreSQL database to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server) ) talk about that, but maybe something is wrong in my command.

```
pg_dump -C -h localhost -U postgres BD.to.move | psql -h server.destiny -U postgres BD.to.move
```

I have password root + password postgres on S1

I have password root + password postgres on S2

however after of run my command `over server1`, in server2 NO'T exist the `BD.to.move`.

My command is wrong?

How I can copy/transfer {BD.to.move + ROLES + SCHEMAS + users, + password, etc...} ?

(in others words, the BD complet to use directly in production over server.destiny)

Comment: First check that `pg_dump` is working, that you're getting proper SQL output.

Comment: yes, ``pg_dump`` work fine, I can get BD in file. But now I want use the option to send BD+SCHEMAS+ROLES to server.destiny without file intermediate

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the argument `BD.to.move` to `psql`, since that database does not exist at the destination. Use `postgres`, which exists.

If you create your dump with `-C`, it will contain a `CREATE DATABASE` statement. In order to restore such a dump, you must connect to an existing database other than the one you want to restore, then `psql` will first create the database, then connect to it and restore the data.