# How do I migrate my local PostgreSQL database to an instance hosted on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, azure-postgresql

New to Microsoft Azure.
I have added a PostgreSQL DB instance to my Azure resource group.

**How do I:**

1. Connect to the newly created PostgreSQL instance?
   On my local windows machine I'm using pgAdmin.
   How do I connect to the instance through pgAdmin?
   Do I need to do something with firewall rules?
2. I have a small sample PostgreSQL database on my local windows machine.
   How do I migrate both the schema and associated data to the instance on Azure?
   I looked at a couple posts, but they didn't make sense to me.

   Is there an Azure service which will help make migration easier?

Comment: Does this answer your first question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/quickstart-create-server-database-portal

Comment: Does this answer your second question: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-copy-database/

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server

Comment: @Cully - that did the trick. I am also able to connect to my Azure DB through pgadmin and see all the data. Q: I'm migrating an .NetCore Web API to Azure, which connects to the PostgreSQL DB.  Should I not be able to use the connection string (from Azure) to point a local copy of my WebAPI to the Azure PostgreSQL DB (I'm using EFCore)? Currently all my DbSets<> are return 0 rows.

Comment: I don't know. You might want to post another question about it. Btw, those links were the first ones I found searching for your problem on Google. In the future, you might want to spend some time looking for documentation first.