# update local Dockerized Postgress DB from an equivalent DB on Azure

Tags: postgresql, docker, pg-dump, azure-postgresql

I have an un-updated local Postgres server, running on a docker container, now I want to update all new records from Production DB,
which runs on Azure Postgres DB.

I'm aware of the pg_dump [as in this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237725/copying-postgresql-database-to-another-server)
but, I'm not clear where should I commend it - the Azure DB doesn't know the Local one and vice versa?

Comment: You can `pg_dump` the database on Azure, copy the dump file to your local system, and then use `psql` or `pg_restore` (depending on how you create the dump) to restore it in your container.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple methods which you can try.

The most common and simple approach is to use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` commands in `bash` to upgrade the database.

In above mentioned method, you first create a dump from the source server using pg_dump. Then you restore that dump file to the target server using pg_restore.

To back up an existing PostgreSQL database, run the following command:

`pg_dump -Fc -v --host=<host> --username=<name> --dbname=<database name> -f <database>.dump`

Once the file has been created, download it in local environment.

After you've created the target database, you can use the pg_restore command and the --dbname parameter to restore the data into the target database from the dump file.

`pg_restore -v --no-owner --host=<server name> --port=<port> --username=<user-name> --dbname=<target database name> <database>.dump`

To find more upgrade methods, you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/how-to-upgrade-using-dump-and-restore#method-1-using-pg_dump-and-psql.

To get more details on `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` methood, please refer Microsoft Official document [Migrate your PostgreSQL database by using dump and restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/howto-migrate-using-dump-and-restore).

Comment: Hey @RSNboim!, I did reproduce this issue and the solution worked for me; do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot?